# How to transfer ownership of Vec into a VecDeque?

Tags: rust, vector, deque

In the following code, I want to transfer the `staged_bytes` vector into the `buffer`. Specifically, I want 'buffer' to take ownership of `staged_bytes` so that I can reuse the `staged_bytes` field for a brand new vector of `u8`.

I show a solution to my problem in the code.
Unfortunately according
to rust documentation, it implies a *copy*
of the vector elements. Since that vector
can be big, I don't want the copy, hence
my desire for an ownership transfer.

I think I can't do it the way I want because the ownership is
at the same time in `staged_bytes` and `buffer`
during the `transfer()`.

So what are the solutions ? I thought of shared
pointers (Rc, etc.) but it seems overkill since
it's not actually shared (maybe the optimizer
figures it out ?)...

```
use std::collections::VecDeque;

struct M {
    buffer : VecDeque<Vec<u8>>,
    staged_bytes: Vec<u8>
}

impl M {
    fn transfer(&mut self) {

        // This is what I want to do (the idea)
        // (it doesn't compile, E0507)
        // self.buffer.push_front(self.staged_bytes);

        // This is what I don't want to do
        // (it compiles)
        self.buffer.push_front(self.staged_bytes.clone());

        // After the transfer, I can start with a new vec.
        self.staged_bytes = Vec::new();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = M {
        buffer : VecDeque::new(),
        staged_bytes: Vec::new()
    };

    s.staged_bytes.push(112);
    s.transfer();
}
```

Comment: [`std::mem::replace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/fn.replace.html) (or just [`std::mem::take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/fn.take.html), since that gives you the default value in return, which is what you want)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `std::mem::take()` here, which returns the value moved from a mutable reference and replaces it with the default value of the type:

```
self.buffer.push_front(std::mem::take(&mut self.staged_bytes));
```

Since the default value of a Vec is an empty vector, you can remove the following assignment (`self.staged_bytes = Vec::new();`) as it is redundant.